# Angular Material Textarea DONT Autofocus

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im adding a text area at the bottom of a modal and the autofocus is having the side effect of scrolling to the bottom. Not having this autofocus would fix the issue. Any idea what is going on.

```
  <mat-form-field >
      <textarea matTextareaAutosize matInput placeholder="Review Notes" [autofocus]="false" [(ngModel)]="reviewNotes"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
```

> "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: Try adding `tabindex="-1"` to the `textarea` tag to avoid the autofocus

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way to control this is by using the MatDialog option for specifically this purpose: the `autoFocus` option in your dialog config. For example:

```
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog) {}
...
openDialog(): void {
  this.dialog.open(MyExampleDialog, {
    autoFocus: false
  });
}
```

The benefit of this is that if the user presses tab once the dialog is open, the 'first tabbable element' still receives focus. Using tabindex="-1" places that element at the end of the focus chain, making it less intuitively accessible.

Comment: Totally forgot about the `MatDialogConfig` options, this is true, and this also keeps the ability to tab on elements if needed?

Comment: Right - this doesn't affect anything to do with tabbing - it just turns off any initial focus.

Comment: kind of odd that the component responsible for opening is telling the sub component how to behave. IMO the dialog should be capable of knowing whether to auto-focus or not. Works well and is a better solution i added a comment to my code code

Answer (score 2):

From the [Angular Material Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#focus-management):

> By default, the first tabbable element within the dialog will receive focus upon open. This can be configured by setting the cdkFocusInitial attribute on another focusable element.
>
> Once a dialog opens, the dialog will automatically focus the first tabbable element.

You can control which elements are tab stops with the tabindex attribute

given this, you can set `tabindex="-1"` property to the element you don't want to recieve focus and it will be ignored.

```
<mat-form-field >
  <textarea matTextareaAutosize tabindex="-1" matInput placeholder="Review Notes" [autofocus]="false" [(ngModel)]="reviewNotes"></textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

EDIT: As mentioned in another answer by **G. Tranter**, another, more useful and appropriate method is to specify `autoFocus: false` as a configuration option on the `openDialog()` method of the MatDialog, this will keep the behavior of tabbable elements intact while removing only the initial focus on load.

Reference here: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig

Thus the `openDialog()` method should be something like this:

```
openDialog(): void {
   this.dialog.open(MyDialog, {
       autoFocus: false
   });
}
```

Comment: No problem, I do think it should be explained better on the docs, those two lines are on different sections... Also keep in mind that this does not seem to work on `a` tags